# Regular expression in jquery or javascript to replace string as mentioned below..

Tags: jquery, replace

Regular expression in jquery to replace string as mentioned below.. Suppose I have a string i.e.

```
<#if ${x} == 'abc' > ${add} <#else if ${y} == 'dfg' > bef </#if>
```

Here I want to remove all `${` and `}` which are inside `if` and `else if` part. But not inside `then` part, how can I do it in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="<#if ${x} == 'abc' > ${add} <#else if ${y} == 'dfg' > <#then ${y} == 'dfg' >";
var thenOut = str.split('then'); 
var required =thenOut[0].replace(/\$/g,"").replace(/\}/g,"").replace(/\{/g,"");
console.log(required+"then"+thenOut[1]);//heres what we need
```

heres the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uLdq5/)